# Geo Targeting with firebase Cloud messaging

Tags: firebase

How can I send different push to different Countries via Cloud messaging? I searched the official documentation for an answer, but I couldn't find anything. I need this for Android. Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to target users by geo in Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The first two options that come to mind are:

1. Define an audience with Google Analytics for Firebase of users in the region. Then use the Notifications panel in the Firebase console to send a message to that audiebnce.
2. Subscribe each user to a topic for their region when they start the app, and then send the message to the topic for each region.